# перевод первого символа слова в верхний регистр

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть строка `qWe zxc Vbn rty Uiop`. Надо чтобы каждое слово начиналось с большой буквы. Сделал так

```
def change_register(my_str):
    s = ""
    for word in my_str.split():
        if word.istitle()== False:
            word = word[0].upper() + word[1:]
        s +="".join(word)
    return s

print(change_register('qwe zxc Vbn rty Uiop'))
#QWeZxcVbnRtyUiop
```

но на выходе получается сплошной текст, как слова можно разделить пробелами? Или может есть более красивое решение

Comment: `'qwe zxc Vbn rty Uiop'.title()` :)

Comment: PS. ``if word.istitle()== False:`` в питоне пишется как  ``if not word.istitle():``

Comment: @insolor не подойдет если в строке несколько больших букв

Comment: @Эникейщик str.capitalize() тоже не подойдет, т.к переведет все остальные буквы переведет в нижний регистр

Comment: Ну у вас ни в вопросе ни в примере нет таких слов, поэтому трудно догадаться, что вам это важно :)

Comment: @Эникейщик ну это моя вина, что не полностью описал суть задачи)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот рабочий вариант вашей функции с учётом комментария насчёт нескольких больших букв.

```
def change_register(my_str):
    s = []
    for word in my_str.split(' '):
        if not word.istitle():
            word = word[0].upper() + word[1:].lower() #убрать .lower(), если не обязательно делать остальные буквы в слове маленькими. 
            s.append(word)
        else:
            s.append(word)
    return ' '.join(s)

print(change_register('qwe zXC Vbn rty Uiop'))
```

Вывод: `Qwe Zxc Vbn Rty Uiop`

Comment: спасибо. Сразу и не додумался что можно записывать в list а из него в строку с join

Answer (score 3):

```
def change_register(my_str):
    return " ".join([word[0].upper() + word[1:] for word in my_str.split()])
```

---

*Объяснение:*

Читайте из конца:

- `my_str.split()` сделает из строки *список слов:* `['qWe', 'zxc', 'Vbn', 'rty', 'Uiop'].`
- `for word in` переходит *по каждом из этих слов.*
- `word[0].upper() + word[1:]` сделает первую букву очередного слова *прописной*.
- всё это вместе с окружающими квадратными скобками (`[]`) делает из того *генетратор списка*, т.е. получаем список тех же слов, но уже *с прописной первой буквой.*
- `" ".join(...)` всё это — т.е. полученный список с прописной первой буквой — используем как параметр метода `.join()` на строку с одним пробелом (`" "`) - результатом будет соединение всех элементов этого списка в одну строку, но с пробелами между ними.

Comment: красиво и в 1 строчку

Comment: Не забудьте добавить к `word[1:]` метод `.lower()`, иначе если в слове есть ещё большие буквы - они такими и останутся.

Comment: @type49, нет, никакой `.lower()`, прочитайте вопрос и комментарии к нему.